# Set value in lookup field in workflow?

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

how can I set only the one value to required lookup field, when I create new item in workflow. I tried use workflow variable, ID but I do something still wrong.

So I have one list A wiht values AB, AC, AD etc. On list B when I select yes in choise field, workflow create new item in list C, where is also lookup field (required) with value from list A. And I only want to set value AB for every created items. Workflow ends with error: Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type. I found that I used wrong data type, but I don´t know what to do.
[image: My workflow set]

Comment: Try to change Title to ID in the last picture.

Comment: You can use ID column for this scenario.

Comment: Yes, change Title to ID works, thanks a lot Roman!!! So easy but ...

Answer (score 2):

Hi, I got stuck in this issue and could solve it so I decided to share that in here:
It's too easy, you should set the **look up the field** as the **Current Item ID**. then it will automatically collect the value for lookup.

in the picture bellow you can see that I've set lookup (my columnm' name) as **1** which means the item with **ID 1** but it will set the value that I need in the connected list. 
Hope to be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Genius!

Column name that the lookup is based on is named: [Lookup ID: ID]

I apply it when an item is added in SharePoint Designer.

I used set [Lookup ID: ID] to [VALUE, use below settings for this]

Field Data To Retrieve [Data Source = Other List / Field from Data Source = ID / Return/ Field as String]

Find the List Item [Field: Name / Value: Data Source Current Item / Field from Source: Name / Return Field as String]

Then you can use SharePoint designer to apply that ID to a different column using a lookup, but the lookup has be ID based. The Lookup by ID can return the other fields you actually want!